# select statement on CASE

Tags: mysql, sql, select, case

Hi im trying to return a resultset from one table. However, I want to add another column on the result set, that is coming from a different table.

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
       CASE (SELECT STATUS FROM OTHERTABLE O WHERE O.ID = M.ID)
          WHEN '1' THEN 'In progress'
          WHEN '2' THEN 'Complete'
       END as STATUS
FROM MAINTABLE M
```

Im getting error:
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted...etc

Comment: There's a pretty big clue in the error message, if you'd care to read it. There's more than one row in `OTHERTABLE` for some particular `ID` value.

Comment: Yup, add `LIMIT 1` to the subquery, or do `MIN(STATUS)` etc. But your subquery isn't working as expected.

Comment: Yes i know that there is more than one row. But my aim is that each row from MAINTABLE M get a STATUS value from OTHERTABLE..

Comment: The resultset returns many rows.. i want each row to have a STATUS value from OTHERTABLE. and the common column between those two tables is the ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join and organize your case

```
SELECT 
  M.ID,
  M.NAME,
  CASE
    WHEN O.STATUS = '1' 
    THEN 'In progress' 
    WHEN O.STATUS = '2' 
    THEN 'Complete' 
  END AS STATUS 
FROM
  MAINTABLE M 
  JOIN OTHERTABLE O 
    ON (O.ID = M.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because your MainTable Id has more then one record in OtherTable

try it

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
   CASE 
      WHEN O.STATUS = '1'  THEN 'In progress'
      WHEN O.STATUS = '2' THEN 'Complete'
   END as STATUS
FROM MAINTABLE M JOIN OTHERTABLE O ON O.Id = M.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Might be you want to this

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
       CASE WHEN O.STATUS = '1' THEN 'In progress'
            WHEN O.STATUS = '2' THEN 'Complete'
       END AS STATUS
FROM MAINTABLE M
INNER JOIN OTHERTABLE O ON O.ID = M.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you'll want a join, not a subquery:

```
SELECT ID, NAME,
CASE O.STATUS 
  WHEN '1' THEN 'In progress'
  WHEN '2' THEN 'Complete'
END as STATUS
FROM MAINTABLE M
INNER JOIN OTHERTABLE O ON O.ID = M.ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use limit 1, based on your error message.

```
SELECT M.ID, M.NAME,
    CASE WHEN O.STATUS = '1' THEN 'In progress'
         WHEN O.STATUS = '2' THEN 'Complete' 
    END as STATUS
FROM MAINTABLE M INNER JOIN OTHERTABLE O ON O.ID = M.ID LIMIT 1
```